# Is there a better way to write this SQL query on SQLZOO?

Tags: sql

So I've managed to get the right answer but I feel like there must be an easier way to go about it.

This is what I have:

```
SELECT f.room_no AS id, MIN(f.chkout_date) AS 'MIN(i)' FROM
(SELECT av.room_no, av.chkout_date, TO_DAYS(MIN(coalesce(c.booking_date,'2016-12-14'))) - TO_DAYS(av.chkout_date) + 1 AS days_avail 
FROM (SELECT a.room_no, a.chkout_date FROM
(SELECT room_no, booking_date, DATE_ADD(booking_date,INTERVAL nights DAY) AS chkout_date FROM booking
JOIN room ON id=room_no
WHERE room_type='single') a LEFT JOIN
(SELECT room_no, booking_date, DATE_ADD(booking_date,INTERVAL nights DAY) AS chkout_date FROM booking
JOIN room ON id=room_no
WHERE room_type='single') b
ON a.room_no = b.room_no
AND b.booking_date = a.chkout_date
WHERE b.booking_date is null) av LEFT JOIN
(SELECT room_no, booking_date FROM booking
JOIN room ON id=room_no
WHERE room_type='single') c
ON av.room_no = c.room_no
AND c.booking_date > av.chkout_date
GROUP BY av.room_no, av.chkout_date) f
WHERE f.days_avail > 3
GROUP BY f.room_no
ORDER BY MIN(f.chkout_date)
```

[image]

Question 14. A customer wants a single room for three consecutive nights. Find the first available date in December 2016

[SQLZOO Q14 with expected answer below](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Guest_House_Assessment_Hard)

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: did you got the correct answer? because you put a date on the query instead of the whole month december

Comment: Yeah, I got the correct date back

Comment: So how you query find the early december date when hard wire the date `'2016-12-14'`

Comment: Because it's filtering out all other dates, which is why I want a different way to query this question. I don't want to hard code the answer

Comment: looks like you cant use window function like `ROW_NUMBER()` ??

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm still very new to this

Comment: Well I try several thing but looks like is a very limited framwork. As I said cant use ROW_NUMBER() or DATEDIFF(). So doesnt make sense try to learn optimize the query if you cant use the newest functions available.

Comment: do you know what db engine they use? and what version?

Comment: MariaDB, don't know which version though